# Inner-join errors on SQL stored procedure

Tags: sql, select, syntax-error, inner-join

I guess I'm just a bit weary, but the answer isn't jumping out for me right now. It throws an error

> SQL Error [4145] [S0001]: An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'WHERE'

Code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spDirectoryLookup]
    (@LookupName nvarchar(100), 
     @ClientNumber bigint)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        DL.subid,
        C.ClientNumber,
        C.ClientName,
        listid,
        dld.Description  
    FROM 
        INTELLIGENT_2414_1.DBO.dirListings DL 
    INNER JOIN 
        Intelligent_2414_1.DBO.cltClients C ON DL.subid = C.subid
    INNER JOIN 
        INTELLIGENT_2414_1.DBO.dirListingDescriptions dld ON dld.listID 

    WHERE 
        Description LIKE '%'+@LookupName+'%'
        AND DL.subid IN (SELECT subid 
                         FROM Intelligent_2414_1.DBO.cltClients C 
                         WHERE C.ClientNumber = @ClientNumber)
END
```

Comment: [mre] [ask] [Help] PS What has your research shown? Including google 'site:stackoverflow.com' search.

Answer (score 2):

The second `join`'s `on` clause is missing a condition. I'm guessing you meant to do this:

```
INNER JOIN INTELLIGENT_2414_1.DBO.dirListingDescriptions dld on dld.listID = DL.listid
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  Mureinik, I think I need to stop coding for now before my eyes complete bleed out :)  I really appreciate it!!